# Error of input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion

I am creating a DB based WebSite application on Asp.NET in C#. I have an error stated `Input string was not in a correct format.`on my browser. Lines shown is:

```
Line 162:        protected string ConvertStatus(object status)
Line 163:        {
Line 164:            int y = Convert.ToInt32(status);
Line 165:
Line 166:            if (y == 1)
```

My related code-behind:

```
protected string ConvertStatus(object status)
{
   int y = Convert.ToInt32(status);


    if (y == 1)
    {
        return "Enabled";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Disabled";
    }
}
```

And this is the label in design page:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# ConvertStatus(Eval("Status")) %>'>  </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How i can solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: In which line you are getting error?

Comment: You need to check that status is a string and its value can be parsed as an integer

Comment: What is your `status` string exactly? Debug and tell us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TryParse` method like this

```
int y;
int.TryParse(status,out y);
```

`TryParse` method is return `bool` that indicate if input is convertible to integer or not. If it is then it will convert into int and assign it to `y` variable. If input can not be convert to int then value of `y` will be `0`.